# Only numbers input widget in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

In kivy, is there a way to use an input form that [in Android] pops-up the number-only keyboard?

Comment: A question like this is better asked on our IRC channel #kivy on freenode.

Comment: @Alexk I have seen that in the docs there is a "slider" Widget (I don't remember the exact name) but I would like very big inputs so it is not suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try looking at the doc?

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.FocusBehavior.input_type ?

Comment: thanks very much...
New Link: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.FocusBehavior.input_type

Comment: I've looked at the linked docs and still don't understand how to pop up a numeric keyboard on Android.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699239/kivy-android-input-type-number